# Construct a truth table for $\left[\left(p\Rightarrow q \right) \land \sim q\right]\Rightarrow \sim p$

Tags: real-analysis, logic

$\left[\left(p\Rightarrow q \right) \land \sim q\right]\Rightarrow \sim p$

I just wanted to check if I did this correctly:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} 
  \text{p} & \text{q} & \text{$p \Rightarrow q$} & \text{$\left(p \Rightarrow q \right) \land \sim q$} & \text{$\left[\left(p \Rightarrow q \right) \land \sim q\right] \Rightarrow \sim p$} \\ \hline
\text{T} & \text{T} & \text{T} & \text{F} & \text{T} \\ \hline
\text{T} & \text{F} & \text{F} & \text{F} & \text{T} \\ \hline
\text{F} & \text{T} & \text{T} & \text{F} & \text{T} \\ \hline
\text{F} & \text{F} & \text{T} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: looks good to me. It would interesting to apply logic transforms to demonstrate the same outcome.

Comment: @Joffan I'm going to be honest with you, I don't even know what that means! haha.  This is my first week in a Real Analysis course, is that something I'll be learning to do?

Comment: Oh, I just realized the final column header in your table doesn't match your question. Which one is correct?

Comment: @Joffan I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table looks good.

Reducing the logical expression:

$[(p\Rightarrow q ) \ \land \sim q]\Rightarrow \sim p$

$\sim [(p\Rightarrow q ) \ \land \sim q]\ \lor \sim p$

$[\sim (p\Rightarrow q ) \ \lor q]\ \lor \sim p$

$\sim (\sim p \ \lor q ) \ \lor (q\ \lor \sim p)$

$\therefore \top$

Answer (score 1):

Your argument seems to be valid due to the following logic:

- Hypothesis:

  1. $q$ happens whenever $p$ happens.
  2. $q $ doesn't happen
- Conclusion: $p$ never happened.